# Format datetime in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, angular, typescript

I'm receiving date and time from the REST API in the below format

```
2016-01-17T:08:44:29+0100
```

I want to format this date and time stamp like

```
17-01-2016 08:44:29
```

It should be dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

How to format this in TypeScript?

Comment: are you talking about just to display on UI if yes then I post my answer .

Comment: @YashveerSingh No. I want to format in typescript, not with pipes

Comment: ok sorry I thought otherwise I will remove my answer . Let me check about how to do it in typescript .

Comment: @YashveerSingh I'm using some third party module for UI and I cannot format in HTML. So i have to handle the format in typescript and send it for rendering

Comment: typescript it self provide some methods like to   new Date().toLocaleString() . have you tried all available ? I am trying them now if it work will post the answer .

Answer (score 16):

you can use moment.js. install moment js in your project

```
 moment("2016-01-17T:08:44:29+0100").format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

for more format option check [Moment.format()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: I cannot use moment.js

Comment: for html part you can do using pipe <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>

Comment: I'm using some third party module for UI and I cannot format in HTML. So i have to handle the format in typescript and send it for rendering

Comment: if you want to do it just using ts then first extract all day,month,year then concat them in string . i use mostly moment.js. may i know why can't you use moment.js ? @Protagonist

Comment: Correct. I know how to concat. But how to extract the date and time into strings?

Comment: typescript is superset of javascript. so every date method will work in typescript. just extract getDay() month() in a variable and in new variable just add all of them like var stringdate=day+'/'+month+'/'+year. in stringdate var you will get string format of you date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133184/discussion-between-amit-suhag-and-protagonist).

Comment: moment.js is deprecated - no more maintained. I prefer day.js instead

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

You can create a `new Date("2016-01-17T08:44:29+0100") //removed a colon` object and then get the month, day, year, hours, minutes, and seconds by extracting them from the `Date` object, and then create your string. See snippet:

```js
const date = new Date("2016-01-17T08:44:29+0100"); // had to remove the colon (:) after the T in order to make it work
const day = date.getDate();
const monthIndex = date.getMonth();
const year = date.getFullYear();
const minutes = date.getMinutes();
const hours = date.getHours();
const seconds = date.getSeconds();
const myFormattedDate = day+"-"+(monthIndex+1)+"-"+year+" "+ hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
document.getElementById("dateExample").innerHTML = myFormattedDate
```

```html
<p id="dateExample"></p>
```

It is not the most elegant way, but it works.

Comment: I'm getting "Object expected" error at var myFormattedDate =day+........;  and Im using typescript

Comment: Did you try to run the snippet? You also have to get rid of the first colon in your api format in order to make a valid Date object

Comment: You can remove the first colon by using the `replace()`-method like this: `var myStr = "2016-01-17T08:44:29+0100".replace(":","");`

Comment: My bad.. there was no colon in the input. Im getting object expected error if I do console.log right after let day= date.getDate(); I'm using typescript

Comment: It should work as it is, but I do not know how you execute your code. You could try to write `var date:Object = new Date("2016-01-17T08:44:29+0100");` Adding an Object type to date.

Comment: There is no mucg difference between var and let except scope. I tried with let day: Date = date.getDate(); but no luck

Comment: You should not write `let day: Date = date.getDate();`, but `let date:Date = new Date("2016-01-17T08:44:29+0100");` the day is a `number`. date is a `Date`. Also try to use `Object` as a type instead of `Date` if it does not compile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133193/discussion-between-protagonist-and-john).

Comment: you need to use parentesis when adding 1 to month: return day+"-"+(monthIndex+1)+"-"+year+" "+ hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;

Comment: @sourcerebels thank you for pointing that out. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: `const day = date.getDate();` -> `const day = date.getDay();`

Comment: @JoopAué `getDay` will give you a number between 0 and 6, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay, not the actual date.

Answer (score 4):

> new Date().toLocaleString()

```
output:
```

> "31/03/2020 ,00:00:0"

(now,your output is string)

Answer (score 3):

Check if this is helpful.

```
var reTime = /(\d+\-\d+\-\d+)\D\:(\d+\:\d+\:\d+).+/;
var originalTime = '2016-01-17T:08:44:29+0100';
var newTime = originalTime.replace(this.reTime, '$1 $2');
console.log('newTime:', newTime);
```

Output:

```
newTime: 2016-01-17 08:44:29
```